# Constructing an object with two fetches from the database does not update some fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am listening to a firestore database (lets call it `ALBUMS`) and when a new object gets created, I fetch the info from firestore. After fetching the info from `ALBUMS` database, I receive `userId` as a field. Here is my listener:

```
 firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("ALBUMS")
      .doc(albumId)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const objectThatIWantToSet = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          const userId = doc.cP.proto.fields.userId.stringValue;
          ...
          // I want to fetch some more info from another db before constructing my object
        });
      });
  };
```

After retrieving `userId`, I need to fetch some more info from **another** database: I want to fetch `userName` from database `users`. Fetching itself is pretty straightforward:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("USERS")
  .doc(userId)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      //take the fields that I need
    }
  });
```

What I do have problem with is the following: from both fetches I need to construct an object, s.t. it will contain the info from `PHOTOS` database and from the `USERS` database. This info, I need to keep it in store. So what I tried is the following:

```js
function FetchInfo(props) {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState(null);

  // I need to set it in useeffect
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("ALBUMS")
      .doc(albumId)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const finalObject = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          //I am getting userId from the first db
          const userId = doc.cP.proto.fields.creator.stringValue;

          let photoInfo = {
            photoId: doc.id,
            photoURL: doc.cP.proto.fields.photoURL.stringValue,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            //I need to insert user data here
          };
          firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(userId)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
              if (snapshot.exists) {
                photoInfo.user = {
                  userName: user.name,
                  userProfilePic: user.profilePicURL
                };
                //here updated result does have users data
                console.log("updated photoInfo: ", photoInfo);
              }
            });
          //my actual result does not have users data
          console.log("actual photoInfo: ", photoInfo);
          return photoInfo;
        });
        //my finalObject does not contain users info
        //finalObj is array of photoInfo objects
        setObj(finalObject);
      });
  }), []);
```

I tried to use `async await` synthax inside `useEffect`, but it didnt let me put `await` infront of the second firebase call (it only let me put `await` infront of the first one, which didnt help).

Any ides would be welcome!

**EDIT** : the fields which I need from the first db (`ALBUMS`) are `photoId`, `photoURL`, `createdAt` and `userId`.

The fields which I need from the second database (`USERS`) are `userName` and `userProfilePic`.

So my final object should be **array** of objects (I call them photoInfo) which have the following json format:

```
photoInfo = {
  photoId:  //taken from the ALBUMS db,
  photoURL:  //taken from the ALBUMS db,
  createdAT: //taken from the ALBUMS db,
  user: {
       userName: //taken from the USERS db,
       userProfilePic: //taken from USERS db
  }
}
```

Again, I am returning array of `photoInfo` objects.

So far I can easily construct the `photoInfo` obj, only with the fields from `ALBUMS` db; the fields from `USERS` db dont get updated.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore document and explain which field you need?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I edited my question, let me know if now is more clear?

Comment: Looks like you update the var names... but essentially `setObj(finalObject)` should be triggered after all promises are resolved. In your case it was ran before the users info was fetched. Also you are attaching a listener to single doc so there's no `.docs` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do by this?

```
const userId = doc.cP.proto.fields.creator.stringValue;
```

If creator is a field containing a string value in the document then you can simply access it by:

```js
const data = doc.data();
const id = doc.id;

const userId = data.creator
```

Try refactoring the `useState` as follows.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // Adding a listener on doc
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("ALBUMS")
      .doc(albumId)
      .onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {
          // An array of requests to get user info
          const userReqs = []
          // Initialized final object
          const finalObject = {}
          // Running a loop on the array field*
          snapshot.data().array_field.forEach((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data();
            const id = doc.id;
            const userId = data.creator;
 
            finalObject[id] = {
              _id: doc.id,
              text: "",
              createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              ...data,
            };

            userReqs.push(
              firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection("users")
                .doc(userId)
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                  if (snapshot.exists) {

                    finalObject[id]["user"] = snapshot.data()
                    //here updated result does have users data
                    console.log(`Added user to ${id}`, snapshot.data());
                  }
                })
            )
          })

          await Promise.all(userReqs)
          console.log("Final Obj", finalObject);
          setObj(Object.keys(finalObject).map((key) => finalObject[key]));
        });
  }, []);
```

Comment: thank you very much, I will try it and I will let you know if it wirks!